# can not connect to phoenix with python phoenixdb

Tags: python, curl, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to connect to phoenix using python plugin  '`phoenixdb`'.

I'm connecting from a server on the same network with phoenix machine.

Here is the code I am using

```
import phoenixdb
import phoenixdb.cursor
database_url = 'http://datanode4:2181'
try:
    conn = phoenixdb.connect(database_url, autocommit=True,user='',password='')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

I get the following error

> phoenixdb.errors.InterfaceError: ('RPC request failed', None, None,
>   RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

Even when I try to use curl, I get  `'Empty reply from server`'

Can you guys help me?